# How to get column types of an existing, named table from SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

How can I represent this query in SQLAlchemy?

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'foo'
```

Comment: Why you need that with SQLAlchemy ? Did you lost the model ?

Comment: I want to be able to read the datatypes for columns in a table `foo`.

Comment: @polku is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Mb, I didn't understood you meant the database types. If it's a mapped table you can iterate columns like this:

```
for c in foo.__table__.columns:
    print(c.type)
```

Comment: Just a table on sql server 2008. I just want a function that returns the column names and types.

Comment: Then I go back to my first question, you don't really need SQLAlchemy, just open a connection and execute your query (3 lines in Python). You can use SQLA automap, but that's really seems overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_data_types(model):
'''return dictionary with column name as key and data type as value'''
    d = {}
    for c in model.__table__.columns:
        d[str(c.name)] = str(c.type)

    return d
```

where model is the sqlalchemy orm table.